# ActiveMQ Artemis memory not reducing in Windows

Tags: activemq-artemis

While posting 500 messages, ActiveMQ Artemis consumes memory on the Windows server. Once those messages are processed the memory is not released. Consequently the response time for the next 300 messages is delayed. How can I resolve this? I am using the master and slave concept in ActiveMQ Artemis.

Do I need to add configuration level changes in `broker.xml`?

Comment: Can you confirm that all the messages were acknowledge successfully and the queue is, in fact, empty? The output of the `artemis queue stat` command would help here. Also, are you certain that garbage collection has already run in the JVM?

Comment: Attached screenshot after execute this command "artemis queue stat"
and I have updated the -Xms12G -Xmx12G in artemis.profile.cmd and in window server only artemis is running

Comment: Any `artemis` command will use the settings in `artemis.profile.cmd` and since you've set both `-Xms12G` and `-Xmx12G` then the `artemis queue stat` command is attempting to allocate 12 gigabytes of memory. Obviously this is **way** more than is needed for a simple administrative command like this and is more than your machine can support. I recommend you set something reasonable like `-Xms256M` instead.

Comment: You means after applying this Xms12G and -Xmx12G memory will be reduce in the window server once message has been processed ?

Comment: No. That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that you can't run the `artemis queue stat` command because you've set `-Xms12G` so running that command is attempting to use 12G of memory which your machine doesn't support. That's why it's reporting, "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue."

Comment: However, it is worth noting that if you use `-Xms12G` the JVM for the broker will _never_ use less than 12G of memory, even if it doesn't really need it. I don't understand why you're setting `-Xms12G` when you're trying to reduce the amount of memory the broker uses.

Comment: Keep in mind that `-Xms` defines the **minimum** amount of memory that the JVM will consume, and `-Xmx` defines the maximum. If you want your JVM's memory footprint to grow and shrink according to demand then you definitely shouldn't set these both to the same value.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Now, I have changed it to -Xms256M and -Xmx12G. I need to achieve a decrease in memory usage after posting 500 messages. Once processed, the memory should decrease automatically . What do I need to do for that, please?

Comment: The first thing to do is to confirm that all the messages were acknowledge successfully and the queue is, in fact, empty. Can you provide the output of the `artemis queue stat` command? Also, can you confirm that garbage collection has run in the JVM after the messages were consumed?

Comment: Added result after execute the "artemis queue stat" yes after cleared all the message also JVM memory is not coming down in window performance
NOTE : USING java 21

Comment: What's the heap size before you send any messages? What's the heap size after you send all the messages? What's the heap size after you consume every message? You still haven't confirmed that GC has run.

Comment: yes GC has run before heap size == 1055.5 MB after heap size == 4876.6 MB after message cleared 4876.6 M this is not reduce

Comment: I set up a quick proof-of-concept on my Linux machine using Java 21 and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.33.0. I made my observations using JConsole to see the heap size. When I first started the broker it consumed about 55MB of heap. I forced GC to run and it dropped down to 33MB or so. Then I sent 500 messages using `artemis producer --message-count 500`. The heap usage went up to 55MB. I consumed the messages using `artemis consumer --message-count 500`, and forced GC again and the heap dropped down to 35MB or so.

Comment: Can you provide a way for me to reproduce the excessive heap usage you're seeing?

Comment: In version 2.31.2 with Java 21, you observed memory increasing after posting 500 messages twice. and After upgrading to version 2.33.0 of your software and switching to Java 11.0.21. However, after the upgrade, even after repeatedly posting 500 messages, memory remains stable without increasing. This suggests that the memory management in the upgraded version is more efficient and stable ? or any issue in 2.31.2 version ?